# chrome-custom-tabs prompt window behavior and remote debugging

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I would like to see if anyone know how `chrome-custom-tabs` handle prompt window for android permission.

Let's take location as an example,

if we listed it in manifest, then in `webview` case, i got a chance to handle if i want to prompt the window for permission.

In regular browser case, chrome will prompt the window for permission.

Does anyone `chrome-custom-tabs` handles the prompt windows? Also, `chrome-custom-tabs`shows me the same `user-agent`as mobile broswer :`user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 6 Build/MPA44I) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.84 Mobile Safari/537.36` is this all expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome-custom-tabs` is just a Chrome app, with customized UI.

Hence:

1. `chrome-custom-tabs` does not do anything special about permissions, it would request location the same way as Chrome would, and if granted, the permission would apply only to chrome. As far as I know, there are no plans to share permissions between Chrome and other apps.
2. `chrome-custom-tabs` intentionally uses the same user-agent as Chrome for Android.